# Prestashop 1.7 stock manager option not showing

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have installed Prestashop 1.7 on my system . I have enabled enable stock management option but still I can't see stock management option. So is that feature removed from 1.7 or what? Should I make some other changes to see that?

Any suggestion and help will be really appreciable.

Regards

Comment: I'll suggest to avoid the use the 1.7 for a production site. The "stable" release is fresh, but still contains bugs.

Comment: Please check the following link, it might help you:

    http://build.prestashop.com/news/here-comes-prestashop-1-7-alpha-4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Advanced Stock Management, this indeed was removed from 1.7.

It is under re-development and it will be added again in the future 1.7+ versions.